# Verificar objeto vazio AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho alguns campos onde passo alguns filtros pra uma consulta no banco. Gostaria de verificar se o objeto está vazio, dessa forma a consulta não seria realizada.

Tentei dessa forma:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Passo o objeto dessa forma:

```
$scope.filtrarContratos = function(contrato) {
      if(isEmpty(contrato)){
         console.log("Inválido");
      }
}
```

Porém o resultado sempre é `false`.

Esse é o resultado que tenho no console quando faço um console.log do objeto:

```
Object { contrato: "" }
```

Já tentei fazer um if pra verificar se  era igual a `""` mas também não funcionou.

Comment: Você já testou esse exemplos? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: @SamirBraga fez bem em compartilhar o link.

Comment: @SamirBraga sim eu tinha tentando e não tinha funcionado, porém acho que resolvi o problema. Ao invés de enviar o objeto inteiro para a função `isEmpty ` que tentei, enviei atributo por atributo e deu certo.

Comment: Já tentou fazer `!!obj`?

Comment: Tem assim também: function isEmpty(obj){
    return (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length === 0);
}

Comment: @durtto também já tinha feito esse teste. Agora está funcionando da maneira que falei, acho que o objeto não estava sendo criado corretamente. pois esse contrato que aparece acima é um atributo também

Comment: Se deu tudo certo, poste a solução como resposta, pode ajudar mais alguém posteriormente.

Comment: várias formas existem, mas você precisa deixar claro a sintaxe do seu objeto. Fique atento ao prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi o problema verificando os atributos do objeto ao invés do objeto inteiro.

Ex:

```
$scope.filtrarContratos = function(contrato) {
    if (isEmpty(contrato.contrato) && isEmpty(contrato.contratante) && isEmpty(contrato.codigoAgrupador)) {
        console.log("Inválido");
    }
}
```

Função que verifica se está vazio:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Html:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="contrato.contrato" placeholder="Contrato"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="contrato.contratante" placeholder="Contratante"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="contrato.codigoAgrupador" placeholder="Cod. Agrupador"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="filtrarContratos(contrato)">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      Filtrar
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Exemplo funcionando:
http://jsfiddle.net/sinkz/HB7LU/21629/

Comment: Então você precisa alterar sua pergunta,

Comment: Alterar de que maneira?

Comment: Verificar se propriedades de um objeto vazio estão vazias com angularJS

Comment: Já especifiquei isso no titulo

Comment: Verificar objeto vazio ou propriedade de um objeto vazio tem uma diferença bem grande @Techies

Comment: @Otto minha ideia inicial era verificar o objeto pois como não consegui deu certo em verificar a propriedade do objeto vazio. Estou  fazendo um fiddle pra lhe mostrar :D

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sinkz/HB7LU/21629/

Answer (score 6):

Função corrigida, aqui funcionou

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj.prop != "" && obj.prop != undefined)
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma também não funcionou.

Comment: Simulei o objeto que foi passado na pergunta `Object { contrato: "" }`, e funcionou

Comment: Veja da maneira que respondi: http://jsfiddle.net/sinkz/HB7LU/21629/

Comment: E aqui está implementando a sua solução: http://jsfiddle.net/sinkz/HB7LU/21630/

Comment: Acho que concordo com vc, pois se `contrato.contrato` estiver preenchido os outros campos não o objeto não está vazio, apenas incompleto. Faz sentido criar uma função `isCompleteObject` que verifique se o objeto está completo. Acho que faltou especificar isso na pergunta.

Comment: Eu não entendo muito bem do funcionamento do JS, mas meio que percebi isso, pois se não preencho os outros campos esses atributos nem aparecem no objeto. Acho que é porque eu não estou "criando" ele com esses atributos no inicio

Answer (score 3):

A function dada como correção não funciona adequadamente, isso porque ele faz *(obj.prop != "")*, e o correto seria *(obj[prop] != "")*. A function que verifica se algum dos itens do objeto está vazio seria:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
            for(var prop in obj) {
                if(obj[prop] != "")
                    return false;
            }       
            return true;
        };
```

A function que usa

*if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))*, só funciona caso queira verificar se determinado item foi adicionado ao objeto, porém se o mesmo item estiver lá, e a idéia é verificar se ele está vazio, então essa função que usa *hasOwnProperty* já não serve.